# concatenate Group by values in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the date field and description in ssrs.In description I have 1,2,1 values.
I need to concatenate description values and remove duplicate values. I need to show the result in another column.

[image]

how can I write the expression for this.? Thanks in Advance

Comment: why don't you make a SQL query in a way that returns your expected output in the last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your SQL Query in a way that will return your expected result or look at this **[answer](https://shakanand.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/ssrs-concatenating-value-from-detail-rows-into-a-single-value/)**.